# How do I run commands in real time in WebdriverIO?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I'm using WebdriverIO with Node.js.

I have a not easy scenario I want to run and I don't want to start all over again every time because the scenario starts with login and takes time.

So what I'm looking for is a way to run 1 command at a time from a certain point of it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is `browser.debug()` it is explained here:
http://webdriver.io/api/utility/debug.html

Answer (score 0):

What I'm doing right now is is to set a debugger and debug the script:

```
client
  .init()
  .windowHandleMaximize()
  .url('URL')
  .setValue('#email_login', 'EMAIL')
  .setValue('#password_login', 'PASSWORD')
  .submitForm('#login_form')
  .click('li=New (Empty)')
  .then(() => {
    console.log(client) //set debugger here
  })
  .end()
```

However, the problem with this method is that if I have an async function I can't run it properly with my IDE (WebStorm).

If for example, I run

```
client.selectByAttribute('data-id', 'library-characters')
  .then(function(aa){
    console.log(aa)
  })
```

When on a breakpoint on `console.log(client)` nothing happens and the only log I get is that the result of this call is a promise.